# SharePoint Online - Custom User properties not found in Refinement

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, search, managed-property

I'm developing against SharePoint Online. Added 2 custom user properties **Agency** and **Company** and populated them for all my users by getting data from the active directory through PowerShell.

I've also created 2 managed properties which are mapping respectively the custom properties.

Now I'm trying to create a PeopleResults page but it seems that I can't find these properties in the refinement webpart.

What should I do? What I'm missing? I've been pulling my hair for two days now.

**EDIT:**

I've done what has been said in the answers.
Instead of creating my own managed properties, I used *RefinableSitring00* and *RefinableString01* which are managed properties provided by SPO. Mapped my custom props on them and reindexed.

Now I can filter with my custom props but it seems that not all the users are concerned. I have more than 600 users with populated custom props and only about 50 can be filtered.

24h passed since the last reindex and nothing changes. What can be the problem of that?

Comment: After making schema changes, you must initiate a reindex request on the site you wish to use the changes in, have you done this? Reindex can take up to 24 hours, at which point you'll see the properties as available refiners.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reindex my site in SPO. Can you tell me where to go?

Comment: @EricAlexander main question updated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making schema changes, you must initiate a reindex request on the site you wish to use the changes in, have you done this? Reindex can take up to 24 hours, at which point you'll see the properties as available refiners.

A reindex can be initiated by going into Site Settings, Search and Offline availability, and clicking the Reindex Site button.

Comment: Which site should I reindex? my peopleresults page is in a teamsite.

Comment: the site you are building this result page on

Comment: Ok, Done.
I will keep you informed after the crawl

Comment: This should do it, I did the same thing a couple weeks ago to get some fields available as refiners in a refinement panel.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help.
Something odd though, when I look into my managed property details, the comboxbox "use in-depth research" is disabled (I'm using SharePoint Online in french, the translation might be incorrect). Is this normal?